# Angularjs ng-repeat filter on multiple layers of the JSON

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying out angularjs framework.

Have a statistics information in the form of JSON like :

```
[{"Region": "USA",
 "People":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Pals"}, {"Id":1,"Name":"Andrew"}]},
 {"Region": "India",
 "People":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Ram"}, {"Id":1,"Name":"Sam"}]}];
```

Wanted to provide a single search option which searches for both region and people's name.
When a people name matches, it must be displayed along with the region.
So, I tried writing a filter to filter on the ng-repeat.

```
 Search : <input id="search" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Search" placeholder="enter text here"/>
  <br/><br/>
  <div ng-repeat="pregion in stats | searchFilter : Search">
      {{pregion.Region}}
      <div ng-repeat="p in pregion.People">
        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;{{p.Name}}
      </div>
    </div>
```

But the filter seems to return multiple arrays, leading to Error: $rootScope:infdig Infinite $digest Loop.

Complete Code in plunker @ http://plnkr.co/edit/Bm8rlizBf49sZ93pDLfS?p=preview

Can anyone suggest an solution or an alternative approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like the problem is that you are manually copying your partially filtered Regions and had a typo (losing Region['People']) so your filtered results don't match the filter when run through it again. Here is the solution I would use:

```
        angular.forEach(input, function(v){
            if(v.Region.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
                cat.push(v);
            } else {
                mod = [];
                tempCat = {};
                angular.forEach(v.People, function(u){
                    if(u.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
                        mod.push(u);
                    }
                });
                if (mod.length > 0) {
                  v = angular.copy(v);
                    v.People = mod;
                    cat.push(v);
                }
            }
        });
        return cat;
```

[plunker 1: simple copy](http://plnkr.co/edit/ky2BUSXncwXbxm8FVy8J?p=preview)

But here is a direct fix of the type if you really want to collapse out the region from non-Region results:

```
        angular.forEach(input, function(v){
            if(v.Region.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
                cat.push(v);
            } else {
                mod = [];
                tempCat = {};
                angular.forEach(v.People, function(u){
                    if(u.Name.toLowerCase().indexOf(search.toLowerCase()) !== -1){
                        mod.push(u);
                    }
                });
                if (mod.length > 0) {
                    tempCat.Categoryid = v.Categoryid;
                    tempCat.CategoryName = v.CategoryName;
                    tempCat.CategoryOrder = v.CategoryOrder;
                    tempCat.CategoryImage = v.CategoryImage;
                    tempCat.People = mod;
                    cat.push(tempCat);
                }
            }
        });
        return cat;
```

[plunker 2: typo fix](http://plnkr.co/edit/vqj2BEInXV2Wm5iqV1fN?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for the solution. But when I apply this to my actual code, I get the error Error: [$rootScope:infdig] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.8/$rootScope/infdig?p0=10&p1=%5B%5B%22fn%3A…0newVal%3A%20%5C%22Entertainment%5C%22%3B%20oldVal%3A%20undefined%22%5D%5D. Think multiple array are getting created. Any idea on this?

Comment: @Pals, I was initially expecting that you just needed to cache like this: http://plnkr.co/edit/0Y9nw7fVJ4BWF414466c?p=preview which will prevent the errors.